# Downloading zip files from a remote server to a local server on Macbook

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, remote-server

I have the following situation-

I have a git repository that I am working on, on a remote server. I have connected to the server via ssh on VScode, and I have a .zip file on that remote server(in the git repository I cloned). I wish to download the .zip file to my local computer.

How do I do this action? I tried to download the .zip file using the scp command, however, due to the way the ssh server is set up, I am having trouble determining the correct hostname to download the file. My friends could do the same thing on their windows platforms by right clicking the zip file in the VScode. I cannot do that either(not working for me). Any help on how I can do this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of something, but if you can give us the SSH command you use to connect, and the path of the file you want, the scp command becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> I have connected to the server via ssh on VScode

Try first to connect in command line, using `ssh`, by using the same paramters as the one used by VSCode to connect to your remote server.
You can see the parameter used in the VSCode "Remote - SSH" console. It usually uses an entry of your `~/.ssh/config` file, which store the remote hostname and user, as well as the right local private key to use.

If you have such an entry 'remoteEntry', the `scp` commands becomes:

```
scp remoteEntry:/path/to/file.zip .
```

Answer (score 0):

Download file over SSH Protocol

```
scp <user>@<ip>:<path to zipped file> .
```

Examples:

1. If the SSH is running on a standard port

   scp root@192.168.10.55:/odoo13/custom.220309.zip .
2. If the SSH is running on a non-standard port, You can specify the port using -P option with SCP command.

   scp -P 2233 root@example.com:/odoo13/custom.220309.zip .

Please do not forget to add space and dot( .) end of the command